# Blender Interference Color node group

Tags: color, reflection

Since English is not an official language here in Japan,
so I'm sorry if there are any mistakes involved in the following sentences.

I am a beginner of Blender 3D software.
However, since I'm interested in simulating metal texture lately,
so suddenly I wondered what it is called
that reflects on metalic faces like a rainbow.

After google searches using a few words,
I knew it is called interference color in English.

And after further searches,
I found one blend file that involves a node group
simulating this color phenomenon.

This is the link for it.

Free download:
Thin-film Interference for Cycles (GPU Compatible)
https://www.blendernation.com/2018/01/08/free-download-thin-film-interference-cycles-gpu-compatible/

I unzipped and opened it in Blender.
It showed the node group in shader editor.

I've attatched a image file , and please see it.
[image: the image of the node group]
In the bottom left section a blank node is inserted, I found.
I thought it seems like a comment sentence
in Programming languages.

And here is my question.
What type of node should I put in?

Any advice is appreciated especially
that is easy to understand for beginners like me.

Comment: Hi :). You can connect a *Normal map* there if you want

Comment: Thaks for a quick response. You gave me a hint. I'll search for a way using this keyword. If I post another question, take good care of it.